# Test for significance in count data

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution

I have count data as below. I want to check if the counts (freckles) between conditions are statistically different in each type (using R). For each condition, we aim to recover 10,000 cells.

I guess the negative binomial model is a good fit usually but I am not sure as I do not have replicates for each type and condition.

```
count <- data.frame(Type = c("c1","c2", "c3"), condition_1 = c(225, 500, 300), condition_2 = c(2100, 1202, 300), condition_3 = c(229, 890, 500))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table and `chisq.test(count[,2:4])`

Comment: Welcome p2016k! Can you explain a bit closer what the data represent? @StephanKolassa's suggestion is the perfect choice if you have sampled individuals of different types and want to test if type has an influence on the condition an individual has. It is not good however, if counts are numbers of freckles, say, of individuals from different types and condition.

Comment: Thanks. The data represent count of cells. Each of c1/c2/c3 is a different cell type detected in different conditions. Ideally, for instance, I want to confirm if the count of cell type c1 in condition_2 (2100) is significantly higher than in condition_1 (225). @StephanKolassa suggestion works if I want to contrast two cell types which is also interesting in my case but is not exactly what I want. So I am not sure if I can answer my question as I do not have replicates in this case.

Comment: Ah, so this is more of the kind "counting freckles" if I understand right :-). Could you expand a little more about that cell counting - is it cells per reference unit, with same reference units, or cells counted in a particular volume, and you know / don't know the volume? And could you add this information to your question (edit your question)? It could be a relevant question for others, and if the information is only in the comments, it gets lost at some stage (comments are deleted routinely after a while).

Comment: Yes, you are right ,they are more counting freckles. For each condition, we aim to recover 10,000 cells in total. Post edited accordingly.

Comment: Oops, sorry, "freckles" was just a metaphor for counts that relate to a given volume - should have been freckles on a face. So you collect 10000 cells *per condition* and determine the types afterwards? But the numbers in your example don't add up to 10000..?

Comment: We aim for 10,000 per condition but the output can differ based on how well the run went. And yes, we determine the types of recovered cells afterwards. As the same cell type can be identified in different conditions, I want to assess if an increase in cell count in one condition is significant.

Comment: Could you explain your experiment a little bit more detailed? The statistical model used for analysis should reflect the way the data are generated, and thus requires to know what is behind the data. You can remove "freckles"- it was just a metaphor, like: you leave petri dishes open for a while, then incubate and count how many of three types of bacteria you find. I tend to believe that this is a case for chi-square test, as suggested by Stephan Kolassa. This would test the hypothesis that there are no differences between conditions, say.